# Matrices multiplication

Tags: python

takes two 2D NumPy matrices as arguments
returns 1 2D NumPy array: the product of the two input matrices
This function will perform the operation Z=X×Y, where X and Y are the function arguments. Remember how to perform matrix-matrix multiplication:

First, you need to make sure the matrix dimensions line up. For computing X×Y, this means the number of columns of X (first matrix) should match the number of rows of Y (second matrix). These are referred to as the "inner dimensions"--matrix dimensions are usually cited as "rows by columns", so the second dimension of the first operand X is on the "inside" of the operation; same with the first dimension of the second operand, Y. If the operation were instead Y×X, you would need to make sure that the number of columns of Y matches the number of rows of X. If these numbers don't match, you should return None.

Second, you'll need to create your output matrix, Z. The dimensions of this matrix will be the "outer dimensions" of the two operands: if we're computing X×Y, then Z's dimensions will have the same number of rows as X (the first matrix), and the same number of columns as Y (the second matrix).

Third, you'll need to compute pairwise dot products. If the operation is X×Y, then these dot products will be between the ith row of X with the jth column of Y. This resulting dot product will then go in Z[i][j]. So first, you'll find the dot product of row 0 of X with column 0 of Y, and put that in Z[0][0]. Then you'll find the dot product of row 0 of X with column 1 of Y, and put that in Z[0][1]. And so on, until all rows and columns of X and Y have been dot-product-ed with each other.

You can use numpy.array, but no functions associated with computing matrix products (and definitely not the @ operator).

You CAN use numpy.dot, but ONLY to multiply vectors, since it can also be used to multiply full matrices.

```
import numpy as np
def mm_multiply(X, Y):
    X = [[1,2], [2,1]]
    Y = [[2,3], [3,3]]
    X = np.array(X)
    Y = np.array(Y)
    [I,J] = X.shape
    [K,H] = Y.shape
    Z = np.zeros((I,H))
    for i in range(I):
        for j in range(H):
            for k in range(K):

                Z[i,j] += X[i,k]*Y[k,j]

    print(Z)

________________
```

My submission code is mv_multiply is not defined, but that is the previous problem - but it might go away with the correct coding. and the other error im getting is: 
    Any help will be much appreciated!! Thanks in advance!

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-38-1b8bf5d47d82> in <module>
          4 A = np.random.random((48, 683))
          5 B = np.random.random((683, 58))
    ----> 6 np.testing.assert_allclose(mm_multiply(A, B), A @ B)

    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/testing/_private/utils.py in assert_allclose(actual, desired, rtol, atol, equal_nan, err_msg, verbose)
       1491     header = 'Not equal to tolerance rtol=%g, atol=%g' % (rtol, atol)
       1492     assert_array_compare(compare, actual, desired, err_msg=str(err_msg),
    -> 1493                          verbose=verbose, header=header, equal_nan=equal_nan)
       1494 
       1495 

    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/testing/_private/utils.py in assert_array_compare(comparison, x, y, err_msg, verbose, header, precision, equal_nan, equal_inf)
        779             return
        780 
    --> 781         val = comparison(x, y)
        782 
        783         if isinstance(val, bool):

    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/testing/_private/utils.py in compare(x, y)
       1486     def compare(x, y):
       1487         return np.core.numeric.isclose(x, y, rtol=rtol, atol=atol,
    -> 1488                                        equal_nan=equal_nan)
       1489 
       1490     actual, desired = np.asanyarray(actual), np.asanyarray(desired)

    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in isclose(a, b, rtol, atol, equal_nan)
       2519     y = array(y, dtype=dt, copy=False, subok=True)
       2520 
    -> 2521     xfin = isfinite(x)
       2522     yfin = isfinite(y)
       2523     if all(xfin) and all(yfin):

    TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Comment: Show the full error message. It looks like you cut off a part at the bottom.

Comment: TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: 1486     def compare(x, y):
   1487         return np.core.numeric.isclose(x, y, rtol=rtol, atol=atol,
-> 1488                                        equal_nan=equal_nan)

Comment: I made a new edit with the whole error code

Comment: You're ignoring your input, and not returning any output. (`print` isn't how you return things.)